# Rcpp memory management

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to convert some character data to numeric as below. The data will come with special caracters so I have to get them out. I convert the data to std:string to search for the special caracters. Dos it creates a new variable in memory? I want to know if there is a better way to do it.

```
NumericVector converter_ra_(Rcpp::RObject x){
  if(x.sexp_type() == STRSXP){
    CharacterVector y(x);
    NumericVector resultado(y.size());
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < y.size(); i++){
      std::string ra_string = Rcpp::as<std::string>(y[i]);
      //std::cout << ra_string << std::endl;
      double t = 0;
      int base = 0;
      for(int j = (int)ra_string.size(); j >= 0; j--){
        if(ra_string[j] >= 48 && ra_string[j] <= 57){
          t += ((ra_string[j] - '0') * base_m[base]);
          base++;
        }
      }
      //std::cout << t << std::endl;
      resultado[i] = t;
    }
    return resultado;
  }else if(x.sexp_type() == REALSXP){
    return NumericVector(x);
  }
  return NumericVector();
}
```

Comment: First, add a sample of your data using `dput(data_set_here)`. Second, yes. You are going to allocate a new vector of memory if the type is not `NumericVector`.

Answer (score 5):

> Does it creates a new variable in memory?

If the input object actually is a numeric vector (`REALSXP`) and you are simply returning, e.g. `as<NumericVector>(input)`, then no additional variables are created. In any other case new memory will, of course, need to be allocated for the returned object. For example,

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector demo(RObject x) {
    if (x.sexp_type() == REALSXP) {
        return as<NumericVector>(x);
    }

    return NumericVector::create();
}

/*** R

y <- rnorm(3)
z <- letters[1:3]

data.table::address(y)
# [1] "0x6828398"

data.table::address(demo(y))
# [1] "0x6828398"

data.table::address(z)
# [1] "0x68286f8"

data.table::address(demo(z))
# [1] "0x5c7eea0"

*/
```

---

> I want to know if there is a better way to do it.

First you need to define "better":

- Faster?
- Uses less memory?
- Fewer lines of code?
- More idiomatic?

Personally, I would start with the last definition since it often entails one or more of the others. For example, in this approach we

- Define a function object `Predicate` that relies on the standard library function `isdigit` rather than trying to implement this locally
- Define another function object that uses the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) to eliminate characters as determined by `Predicate`; and if necessary, uses `std::atoi` to convert what remains into a `double` (again, instead of trying to implement this ourselves)
- Uses an Rcpp idiom -- the `as` converter -- to convert the `STRSXP` to a `std::vector<std::string>`
- Calls `std::transform` to convert this into the result vector

---

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

struct Predicate {
    bool operator()(char c) const
    { return !(c == '.' || std::isdigit(c)); }
};

struct Converter {
    double operator()(std::string s) const {
        s.erase(
            std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), Predicate()),
            s.end()
        );

        return s.empty() ? NA_REAL : std::atof(s.c_str());
    }
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector convert(RObject obj) {
    if (obj.sexp_type() == REALSXP) {
        return as<NumericVector>(obj);
    }
    if (obj.sexp_type() != STRSXP) {
        return NumericVector::create();
    }

    std::vector<std::string> x = as<std::vector<std::string> >(obj);
    NumericVector res(x.size(), NA_REAL);

    std::transform(x.begin(), x.end(), res.begin(), Converter());
    return res;
}
```

---

Testing this for minimal functionality,

```r
x <- c("123 4", "abc 1567.35 def", "abcdef", "")
convert(x)
# [1] 1234.00 1567.35      NA      NA

(y <- rnorm(3))
# [1]  1.04201552 -0.08965042 -0.88236960

convert(y)
# [1]  1.04201552 -0.08965042 -0.88236960

convert(list())
# numeric(0)
```

---

Will this be as performant as something hand-written by a seasoned C or C++ programmer? Almost certainly not. However, since we used library functions and common idioms, it is reasonably concise, likely to be bug-free, and the intention is fairly evident even at a quick glance. If you *need* something faster then there are probably a handful of optimizations to be made, but there's no need to begin on that premise without benchmarking and profiling first.

Comment: How about this line: 
    std::string ra_string = Rcpp::as<std::string>(y[i]);
when I get a STRSXP, I conver it to std:string. Does it cost more memory?
Really thank you for the answer.

Comment: Yes calling `Rcpp::as<std::string>` will require allocating memory for an `std::string`. In general any conversion between types will require memory to be allocated for the type you are converting to. The only reason this does not happen with `Rcpp::as<NumericVector>(REALSXP)` is because `NumericVector` is essentially just a wrapper class storing a `REALSXP` internally.